# Building project in Maven from SVN tag

Tags: maven, release-management, maven-release-plugin

We currently use Maven (v2.2.1) to manage our Java projects, including using release:prepare and release:perform to version our releases.

While this is all pretty simple, I find myself needing to produce the build artifacts from a previous release - is it possible to have maven checkout a given (svn) tag, and build the artifacts from that version?

ie. I have the following tags for a project in SVN:

- project-1.0.0
- project-1.0.1
- project-1.1.0

I would like to build 'project-1.0.1' (or in fact any tag from that project).

**Edit:**

In order to clarify what I'm trying to do, consider the `release:prepare` and `release:perform` goals.

During `:prepare` and `:perform` Maven asks what SCM tag should be used for this release, and afterwards creates the tag, checks out the source for this tag into a separate directory in order to produce a sort of cleanroom build of your project.

What I would like to do is actually perform this last part, whereby **I** supply the SCM tag (on the command line, rather than hard coding it in the pom, as that would not be particularly flexible), and Maven happily goes off to checkout the code and perform a cleanroom build, resulting in the final build artifact, in exactly the same way as `release:perform`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [bootstrapping a project](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html) using [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html).

By defining a pom, which contains your scm configuration with the specified tag, as well as the desired maven goal, you can checkout a tag of your choice and build the same.

The link contains an example configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however we already have the <scm> section in our pom, as I believe it is required in order to properly use release:prepare and release:perform. What I'm looking for is a way to rebuild a particular artifact from its tag (as created using the release process). This isn't something I want done every time, so I dont really want to include the tag in the pom itself.